# Iterating through a json in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Help please, guys.

After an Ajax call, I have a JSON object with two rows (users). I have dynamic id's as I intend to load some content (a form to edit the user details) on the page. My problem is each user row that the FOR loop generates has the same ID. So all of the Ajax generated rows have the same ID, 48 in this case.
Here is the code..

```
// Get the admin information
var loadAdmin = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        id: id,
        cache: false,
        url: 'scripts/administratorsList.php?id=' + id
    }).done(function(data) {
        var adminData = JSON.parse(data);

        for (var i in adminData) {
            var userId = adminData[i].id;
            $('#adminList').append('<li class="media"><a href="#" class="media-link" id="edit' + userId + '"><div class="media-left"><img src="assets/images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></div><div class="media-body"><div class="media-heading text-semibold">' + adminData[i].userName + '</div><span class="text-muted">Administrator</span></div><div class="media-right media-middle text-nowrap"><span class="text-muted"><i class="icon-pin-alt text-size-base"></i>&nbsp;' + adminData[i].userCompany + '</span></div></a></li>')

            // Add the edit form view here          
            $('#edit' + userId).on('click', function(userId) {
                var userId = adminData[i].id;
                $('#userConfig').append('Here I will generate the form to edit user ' + userId); // This is where the ID stays the same. I have used .append over .html for debugging purposes. Each row returns an ID of 48
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Below is the JSON file

```
[{
    "id": "17",
    "userName": "Mark Bell",
    "userCompany": "Pro Movers",
    "userTelephone": "12345678911",
    "userEmail": "info@info.uk",
    "userPassword": "md5hash",
    "userUAC": "6",
    "originalUAC": "6",
    "userRegistered": "20150826",
    "activationKey": "0",
    "userLastLoggedIn": "20160302",
    "userBranch": "0",
    "userAdmin": "0"
}, {
    "id": "48",
    "userName": "demo",
    "userCompany": "Monstermove",
    "userTelephone": "12345678912",
    "userEmail": "info@info.uk",
    "userPassword": "demo",
    "userUAC": "6",
    "originalUAC": "6",
    "userRegistered": "20160305",
    "activationKey": "0",
    "userLastLoggedIn": "20160305",
    "userBranch": "3",
    "userAdmin": "3"
}]
```

Thanks in advance

With Jacub's implementation

for(var i in adminData)
        {

```
        var userId = adminData[i].id;
        storeValueToRemainSame(userId);

    }

    function storeValueToRemainSame(userId) {
    $('#adminList').append('<li class="media"><a href="#" class="media-link" id="edit' + userId + '"><div class="media-left"><img src="assets/images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></div><div class="media-body"><div class="media-heading text-semibold">' + adminData[i].userName + '</div><span class="text-muted">Administrator</span></div><div class="media-right media-middle text-nowrap"><span class="text-muted"><i class="icon-pin-alt text-size-base"></i>&nbsp;' + adminData[i].userCompany + '</span></div></a></li>')

        // Add the edit form view here          
        $('#edit' + userId).on('click', function(userId) {
            var userId = adminData[i].id;
            $('#userConfig').append('Here I will generate the form to edit user ' + userId); // This is where the ID stays the same. I have used .append over .html for debugging purposes. Each row returns an ID of 48
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are referencing value outside of the handler which changes, therefore the last value is retained.

```
for(var i in data) {
    var value = i;
    $('#someId').on('click', function(){
         console.log(value);
    });
}
```

The only written value will be the last one as the reference to it will remain. 
Possible solution is for example:

```
function storeValueAndHandleClickEvent(value){
    $('#someId').on('click', function(){
         console.log(value);
    });
}

for(var i in data) {
    storeValueAndHandleClickEvent(i);
}
```

EDIT: If I use the same code as in the question

```
for (var i in adminData) {
    var userId = adminData[i].id;
    storeValueToRemainSame(userId);
}

function storeValueToRemainSame(userId) {
    $('#adminList').append('<li class="media"><a href="#" class="media-link" id="edit' + userId + '"><div class="media-left"><img src="assets/images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-circle" alt=""></div><div class="media-body"><div class="media-heading text-semibold">' + adminData[i].userName + '</div><span class="text-muted">Administrator</span></div><div class="media-right media-middle text-nowrap"><span class="text-muted"><i class="icon-pin-alt text-size-base"></i>&nbsp;' + adminData[i].userCompany + '</span></div></a></li>')

    // Add the edit form view here          
    $('#edit' + userId).on('click', function(userId) {
        var userId = adminData[i].id;
        $('#userConfig').append('Here I will generate the form to edit user ' + userId); // This is where the ID stays the same. I have used .append over .html for debugging purposes. Each row returns an ID of 48
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jacub.
The click handler is generated dynamically and I can't see how to do this with your suggestion. With '#someId' being generated outside of the while loop, I would not be able to append the dynamic ID would I?

Comment: @Jacub Balhar. I had a stray var userId = adminData[i].id which was reverting the userId back to an error. You fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code outside ajax

You will use event delegation an will select the id from the id of the dynamically added dom element

```
  $('ul').on('click','div[id^="edit"]',function() {
                    var userId = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);
                    $('#userConfig').append('Here I will generate the form to edit user ' + userId); // This is where the ID stays the same. I have used .append over .html for debugging purposes. Each row returns an ID of 48
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, Madalin. Sorry for the delay. I had to research event delegation there. I added the code that you suggested to the page both before and after the Ajax call, I asked it to log the userId to the console and I cannot get any output
  
    $('ul').on('click','div[id^="edit"]',function() {
    var userId = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);
    console.log(userId);
    //$('#userConfig').append('Here I will generate the form to edit user ' + userId); // This is where the ID stays the same. I have used .append over .html for debugging purposes. Each row returns an ID of 48
   });